# Android switch button turn on automatically while detecting object

Tags: android

I'd like to use Rasp Pi to connect a motion sensor while the objects being detected ,it would immediately send a data on the Android phone and prompt a notification by using WIFI.However, I am struggling how can I actually implement it.If someone has used this sort of idea that Please give me some advices.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Connect your raspberry with your android phone either via Google Near By 2.0 or use firebase realtime database for connectivity.

Comment: Thank you so much,mate.If you got more detail about it that please share much more ideas to me.Cheers